# how to keep the time on screen

Tags: clock

I've got a Samsung Galaxy 3 tablet (the 10 inch one) running android 4.4.2.
My wife would like to be able to see the time on it while playing her apps. Is there a way to do this? I couldn't see anything to do it in the settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Play store and search for 'Float Clock'. You'll find something for sure.

I'll try to post a link of certain application when I get to my computer :-)

Comment: @john You can also just swipe the top of the screen if it's running KitKat and see the notification bar with the time while you play. Mani maybe link to some apps that might be of use?

Comment: @RossC Most of your comment doesn't seem to have anything to do with the answer you're commenting on. Perhaps you wanted to post another answer?

Comment: @RossC if so: the "notification area" wasn't just added with Kitkat. Just checking my device with the "oldest Android version": ICS has the time in there as well (not just in the bar, but also in the "opened area"). Also note: on tablets, it often is not at the top, but at the bottom-right corner ;)

Comment: Even when in a full screen game, you shouldn't be able to see the notification AFAIK @izzy

Comment: @RossC you might not *see* it then, but that's not the part I'm referring to. Read your first comment again: *swipe **the top of the screen** if it's running KitKat and see the notification bar*. Not sure, but you might have to do so with *the bottom of the screen* on a tablet (*if* swiping still opens it when in full-screen mode, that is) ;) And the "time displayed" I was referring to was in the *opened notification area* (where it was added IMHO with ICS; don't remember seeing it in that place with GB).

Comment: Thanks, my wife gets frustrated that the time isn't just there like her older tablet always was. This should make her happier.